# Using Manipulate to dynamically correct the baseline of a signal

Tags: plotting, manipulate, fitting

i have data with a baseline and will correct it with a polynomial fit using `Manipulate` to see immediatly the changes in the resulting spectrum. It works so far, but the problem is the definition of the function `fbaseline` in the `Manipulate` Part. Mathematica keeps calculating until my RAM is full and then the computer freezes. If I leave out the "_" (fbaseline[x]=...) the code doesn't work anymore, because I can't apply the `Map` function. Do you have an idea, how I can avoid this?

Here is a minimal working example:

Generate Data:

```
  datafunc = Exp[-0.2 x] + Exp[-0.1 (x - 10)^2/0.2];
  data = Table[{x, datafunc + .05 RandomReal[{-1, 1}]}, {x, 0, 25, 0.05}];
  ListPlot[data]
```

Initial values:

```
  xi = {5, 15};
```

Manipulate part:

```
  Manipulate[
    baselinedata = Cases[data /. {x_, y_} /; (x > x1 && x < x2) -> 0, {x_, y_}];
    fbaseline[x_] = f[x, n] /. FindFit[baselinedata, f[x, n], Array[a, {n + 1}, 0], x];
    datablk = Transpose[Join[{data[[All, 1]]}, {data[[All, 2]] - Map[fbaseline, data[[All, 1]]]}]];
    Show[ListPlot[{data, baselinedata, datablk}, PlotStyle -> {{Gray, PointSize[Medium]}, {Orange, PointSize[Medium]}, {Red, PointSize[Medium]}}, PlotRange -> All],Plot[fbaseline[x], {x, 0, 25}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Dashed}],
    Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Point[{{x1, 0}, {x2, 0}}]}], ImageSize -> 1000],
    {{n, 6}, 2, 8, 1}, {{x1, xi[[1]]}, 0, 15}, {{x2, xi[[2]]}, 5, 25}
    ]
```

Another problem is, that the axis at y=0 dissapears for some values.

Previous version (not working without the data):
Here is the code i have so far:

```
 f[x_Symbol, b_Integer] := Array[a, {b + 1}, 0].x^Range[0, b];´
 (*Initial values for excluded ranges*)
 xi = {441, 1151};
 region1 = {{0, 4000}, {-1000, 25000}};
 region2 = {{0, 4000}, {Min[data], Max[data]}};

 Manipulate[
   baselinedata = 
   Cases[data /. {x_, y_} /; (x > x1 && x < x2) -> 0, {x_, y_}];
   xi = {x1, x2};
   fbaseline[x_] = f[x, n] /. FindFit[baselinedata, f[x, n], Array[a, {n + 1}, 0], x];

   datablk = Transpose[Join[{rawdata[[All, 1]]}, {data[[All, 2]] - Map[fbaseline, rawdata[[All, 1]]]}]];
   Show[ListPlot[{data, baselinedata, datablk}, 
   PlotStyle -> {{Gray, PointSize[Medium]}, {Orange, 
   PointSize[Medium]}, {Red, PointSize[Medium]}}, 
   PlotRange -> region],
   Plot[fbaseline[x], {x, 400, 4000}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Dashed}],
   Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Point[{{x1, 0}, {x2, 0}}]}],
   ImageSize -> 1000],
{{n, 6}, 2, 8, 1}, {{x1, xi[[1]]}, 400, 600}, {{x2, xi[[2]]}, 800, 1300}, {{region, region2, "Plotregion"}, {region1 -> "Zoom", region2 -> "All"}}
```

]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using ContinuousAction -> False as option for Manipulate? Is disables evaluation while dragging the sliders and can reduce the number of evaluations and therefore it takes at least longer until memory is full.

Comment: Try setting `$HistoryLength = 0`. See [`$HistoryLength`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$HistoryLength.html) for details.

Comment: Hi, i have added a minimal working example. Both suggestions doesn't work, the bar on the right side is "black" so Mathematica keeps calculating. Thanks so far!

Comment: Add `TrackedSymbols :> {n, x1, x2}` to your `Manipulate`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have rewritten your code to remove function definitions from the first argument of `Manipulate`. It is always a bad idea to define functions in the first argument of `Manipulate` -- such functions get redefined every time the front end refreshes the visible contents of the `Manipulate`. I have also put some effort on reducing the amount of evaluation done when a slider is moved.

What I have done appears to have cured all the bad behavior you describe. The resulting `Manipulate` is quite responsive.

```
f[x_Symbol, n_Integer] := Array[a, {n + 1}, 0] . x^Range[0, n]
baselinedata[data_, u1_?NumericQ, u2_?NumericQ] := Select[data, ! (u1 < #[[1]] < u2) &]
fbaseline[x1_?NumericQ, x2_?NumericQ, n_Integer, data_] :=
  Block[{x}, 
    f[x, n] /. FindFit[baselinedata[data, x1, x2], f[x, n], Array[a, {n + 1}, 0], x]]
datablk[x1_?NumericQ, x2_?NumericQ, n_Integer, data_] :=
  Block[{poly},
    Function[poly[x_] := #][fbaseline[x1, x2, n, data]];
    Transpose[Join[{data[[All, 1]]}, {data[[All, 2]] - Map[poly, data[[All, 1]]]}]]]

SeedRandom[1];
data = Table[
    {x, Exp[-0.2 x] + Exp[-0.1 (x - 10)^2/0.2] + .05 RandomReal[{-1, 1}]}, 
    {x, 0, 25, 0.05}];

With[{xi1 = 5, xi2 = 15},
  Manipulate[
    Show[
     ListPlot[{data, baselinedata[data, x1, x2], datablk[x1, x2, n, data]},
       PlotStyle -> {{Gray, PointSize[Medium]}, 
                     {Orange, PointSize[Medium]},
                     {Red, PointSize[Medium]}},
       PlotRange -> All],
     Plot[fbaseline[x1, x2, n, data], {x, 0, 25}, 
       PlotStyle -> {Black, Dashed}], 
     Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Point[{{x1, 0}, {x2, 0}}]}], 
     ImageSize -> 500],
  {{n, 6}, 2, 8, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {{x1, xi1}, 0, 15, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {{x2, xi2}, 5, 25, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]]
```

[image: manipulate]